# Cordova platform add android error in windows7

Tags: cordova

Cordova adding android platform throws an error in my windows7. I have made sure all my paths works fine.

> java -version
>   ant -version works fine
>   android also works fine

```
    C:\Users\kirthi\Hello>cordova -d platform add android
    cordova library for "android" already exists. No need to download. Continuing.
    Checking if platform "android" passes minimum requirements...
    Creating android project...
    Running bin/create for platform "android" with command: ""C:\Users\kirthi\.cordo
    va\lib\android\cordova\3.3.0\bin\create"  "C:\Users\kirthi\Hello\platforms\andro
    id" "com.hello.com" "HelloWorld"" (output to follow)

    Error: An error occured during creation of android sub-project.

    at C:\Users\kirthi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\src\platform.js:
    282:30        
    at exithandler (child_process.js:633:7)  
    at ChildProcess.errorhandler (child_process.js:649:5)  
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)  
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:795:12)
```

Comment: Check if you have installed the latest SDK platform. Cordova projects are created with targetsdk=19 so it fails if it's not installed.

Comment: @QuickFix targetsdk is already 19 and am still facing the problem. Anyways for your post.

Comment: try to run the following command: `C:\Users\kirthi\.cordo
    va\lib\android\cordova\3.3.0\bin\check_reqs.bat` to check if it says everything's ok or reports error.

Comment: @QuickFix It shows the following error on running the check_reqs.bat 'cscript' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of error when adding android platform, you can run the following command to have more info on what's wrong:

```
%userprofile%\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.3.0\bin\check_reqs.bat
```

In your case :

> 'cscript' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file

Check if you have cscript.exe in the `%systemdrive%\windows\system32` folder and that %systemdrive%\windows\system32 is in your path (if your system is in the c drive, you should see C:\windows\system32 somewhere when you run the command

```
set path
```

(maybe you messed-up with the path when you modified it to add ant and android sdk?)

- If C:\windows\system32 is in the path and cscript.exe is in this folder, try to run cscript in a shell and see it it outputs errors
- If C:\windows\system32 is not in the path then correct the path
- if you don't find C:\windows\system32\cscript.exe, maybe you uninstalled `Windows Scripting Host` from the windows features?